# How can I send command to my Python script via application on Android phone?

Tags: python, android, sockets

i have my server.py which i wanna run on my PC

```
print ('# server.py')
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 2137

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket, addr = s.accept()
    message = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print('{} > {}'.format(str(addr), message))
    clientsocket.close()
```

and my client.py which i wanna transform into an application for android phone

```
print ('# client.py')
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 2137

while True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    message = input('message: ')
    s.send(message.encode('ascii'))
    s.close()
```

is it possible? to send data from my phone to my pc? and how could i do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to send data from your phone to your computer. But you have to take care of port forwarding (in the router configuration) to make your PC visible from outside the network. 
In other words, you have to tell your router to forward requests going to a specific port to your PC at port xyz.

Comment: i know it, i just wanna know how to send data from my phone to my computer by local network, how can i make my own application for android to do it?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did not see the android tag and thought this part was already in place.